# Why does cold icing slide off a warm cake?

Tags: temperature, friction, adhesion

As in the title: why does cold icing slide off a warm cake?

I've been told that it's because a thin layer at the bottom of the mass of icing interacting with the surface of the cake melts to some degree, which causes the rest of the icing to "slide over it". However, it seems like this would lead to a liquid trail being left behind by the mass of icing as it slides across the cake. In my experience, the entire mass of icing slides around the cake leaving little to no trail, especially if the icing is sufficiently cold to not melt so quickly on contact with the warm cake.

Does the difference in temperature between two contacting surfaces have an effect on certain properties, like adhesion or the coefficient of friction? Or is the simpler explanation correct?

Comment: It seems to me likely that it's a thin layer of fat that will form at the interface and allow sliding.

Comment: I agree .you may not be able to see it but something is being left behind.   Use your tongue....do u taste frosting if you lick a slid-cake?